# Is こられた (from 来られた from 来られる) here working as a passive helping?

Tags: words, passive-voice, honorifics, subsidiary-verbs

I came across two paragraphs in which こられた is mentioned.

1st paragraph:

> 萩生田文部科学大臣は、ＮＨＫの取材に対し、「*報道が事実だとすれば、これまで体調が悪い中でも業務を続けて**こられた**のに、ここにきて辞任されるのは非常に残念だ*。まだお若いので、今後は体調に気をつけていただきながら後輩への指導をしっかりしてもらいたい」と述べました。

2nd paragraph:

> 自民党の稲田幹事長代行は、ＮＨＫの取材に対し、「全く予想していなかった事態なので、正直、驚いている。まだ新型コロナウイルスが収束せず、先行きが見通せない状況で、安全保障環境も厳しい状況なので政治空白を作ってはいけない。安倍総理大臣には、政権を奪還してから8年近く、経済、安全保障、*それに外交で日本の存在感を高めた意味からも、全身全霊で頑張って**こられた**と敬意を表したい*」と述べました。

I am inclined to believe that こられた is working here as helping verb for 続ける and 頑張る。

1. 報道が事実だとすれば、これまで体調が悪い中でも業務を続けてこられたのに、ここにきて辞任されるのは非常に残念だ。

   If the report is a true thing + until now + physical condition が sick+while でも job を continue こられた(was to come?)のに、。。。

   In other words: If the report is true, and until now while being sick he WAS TO COME to continue to work, and to here he (abe) is being made to quit, it is very bad.
2. 。。。それに外交で日本の存在感を高めた意味からも、全身全霊で頑張ってこられたと敬意を表したい。。。

   moreover + diplomacy で feeling of presence を enhanced meaning からも、whole heart and soul で persevere + WAS TO COME と respect を I want to express.

   In other words: Moreover, because, by diplomacy he also enhanced the meaning of japanlandia, with heart and soul he WAS TO COME to persevere, I want to express my respect.

Are my surmises correct in regards to こられた working as helping passive verb?

Answer (score 3):

This こられる is the rareru-form of くる, and くる is a subsidiary verb you probably already know. Here, both -てくる means something like "up until now".

- [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010)

Why こられる instead of くる? Although rareru-form is usually a passive-form, it has many uses, one of which is honorific.

- [Meaning of お支払いを希望される方](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23921/5010)
- [What is the implicit subject of 無断利用されています。?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28981/5010)
- [「お誕生日には何をされたんですか」Why される?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42722/5010)
- [Is there a reason why the passive and the potential form are identical (at least for える/いる verbs)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60050/5010)

In conclusion, this 頑張ってこられた is an honorific version of 頑張ってきた, and it is interchangeable with 頑張っていらっしゃった.