# Why 望む is in passive here?

Tags: grammar

I am confused why 望む is written in passive form below:

[image]

I understand 黒瀬くんの進学を望まれる as "mother wants Kurose to pursue further education." I wonder if 望む is written in passive form to show respect?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28981/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4946/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42722/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/80439/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23921/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36179/9831

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as you supposed, the auxiliary verb (ら)れる is employed here to show respect to the subject of the verb 望む (which is Kurose's mother), and not to mean passive.